# Error: String not recognized as a valid boolean on a varchar?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, aspxgridview

I have a gridview with a checkbox, that when selected inserts the selected items into two databases. The error occurs at a specific insert parameter that is a data type nvarchar. I'm not sure why it's giving me a boolean error. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I can post code if needed.

Comment: Ehem, yeah code would be needed.

Comment: What is the DataType for the "Inactive" field in the second table?

Comment: The inactive field is a bit.

Comment: You have mentioned the DataType of lactive as Boolean
and assigning its Default Value as "0" i.e String(varchar).
This is the reason its giving error. Make the DataType same at both place.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so let's get started. First, this has got to change from this:

```
sqlds1.UpdateCommand = String.Format(
    "UPDATE Fees SET Inactive = '1' WHERE Description = '{0}'",
        Request("cbusno"))
```

to this:

```
sqlds1.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE Fees SET Inactive = '1' WHERE Description = @Desc"
sqlds1.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Desc", Request("cbusno"))
```

Next, this has got to change from this:

```
sqlds2.UpdateCommand = String.Format(
    "UPDATE OLLicenses SET lactive = '1' WHERE cbusno = '{0}'",
        Request("cbusno"))
```

to this:

```
sqlds2.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE OLLicenses SET lactive = '1' WHERE cbusno = @no")
sqlds2.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@no", Request("cbusno"))
```

Next, you'll want to use a different API here:

```
Sqldatasource1.Clear()
Sqldatasource1.InsertParameters.Add("cbusno", Request("cbusno"))
Sqldatasource1.InsertParameters.Add("licsubcategory", tb5.Text)
Sqldatasource1.InsertParameters.Add("description", tb5.Text)
Sqldatasource1.InsertParameters.Add("nfee", tb2.Text)
Sqldatasource1.InsertParameters.Add("lactive", "0")
Sqldatasource1.InsertParameters.Add("tadded", DateTime.Now.ToString())
Sqldatasource1.InsertParameters.Add("cuserid", Session("Username"))
Sqldatasource1.InsertParameters.Add("myfield", Request("myfield"))
Sqldatasource1.Insert()
```

This allows the data source to handle the typing for you.

Same as aforementioned with this block:

```
SqldatasourceFee.InsertParameters.Add("myfield", Request("myfield"))
SqldatasourceFee.InsertParameters.Add("Amount", tb2.Text)
SqldatasourceFee.InsertParameters.Add("CalculatorDescription", (string)clicnotxt.Table(0)(0))
SqldatasourceFee.InsertParameters.Add("Dept", "Business Tax")
SqldatasourceFee.InsertParameters.Add("Module", "Business Tax")
SqldatasourceFee.InsertParameters.Add("Type", tb4.Text)
SqldatasourceFee.InsertParameters.Add("SubType", tb5.Text)
SqldatasourceFee.InsertParameters.Add("Inactive", "0")
SqldatasourceFee.InsertParameters.Add("UserCreated", Session("Username"))
SqldatasourceFee.InsertParameters.Add("Description", Request("cbusno"))
SqldatasourceFee.Insert()
```

Now, take note to a couple of things. First, notice I casted this value to a `string` here `(string)clicnotxt.Table(0)(0)`. That value was suspect to me, but I don't believe it's the source of your error. I think the issue here are stuff like this:

```
SqldatasourceFee.InsertParameters.Add("Inactive", "0")
```

I'm thinking, but can't be 100% sure, that it should be:

```
SqldatasourceFee.InsertParameters.Add("Inactive", "False")
```

Finally, when you build a `SqlDataSource` inline like this:

```
Dim sqlds1 As SqlDataSource = New SqlDataSource()
```

you need to wrap it in a `Using` because it implements `IDisposable`:

```
Using sqlds1 As SqlDataSource = New SqlDataSource()
    sqlds1.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myconnectionstring").ConnectionString
    sqlds1.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE Fees SET Inactive = '1' WHERE Description = @Desc"
    sqlds1.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Desc", Request("cbusno"))
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I'm not the greatest at programming yet, so I'm still learning.

Comment: @Control, of course; that's why it needs to be broken down for you. I'm not finished yet.